# Ubuntu Core on Raspberry Pi: Hide cursor on boot

Tags: chromium, snap, ubuntu-core, kiosk

I'm making a web kiosk using Ubuntu core on a Raspberry Pi, but I want to permanently hide the cursor. I tried using unclutter but was unable to install it with snap. For displaying the web page I used Chromium-mir-kiosk. There is an option to hide the cursor but it doesn't hide until the mouse is moved. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

```
snap set mir-kiosk cursor=none
```

https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/configuring-mir-kiosk-a-masterclass/8150

Comment: It would be nice to surround your answer's code by some explanation.